# Integrate Facebook comments with native comments

Tags: plugins, comments, facebook

I've finally installed the [Facebook Comments plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/) to allow readers to comment using their Facebook identity.

After the installation, I got two different comment sections, with two separate comment chronologies, two comment counters and two comment text boxes.

Is there a way to integrate the two comment sections?

Comment: Have you checked the [Facebook Comments support threads](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook-comments-plugin)?  You may find your answer there.

Comment: Didn't find any relevant answer there.